# How to avoid new packages on dist-upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, kubuntu

Recently Kubuntu 17.04 wants to install `nodejs` and other **NEW packages** on `dist-upgrade`:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5 libuv1 nodejs qml-module-org-kde-purpose
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kdeplasma-addons-data kwin-addons plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-runners-addons
  plasma-wallpapers-addons plasma-widgets-addons
```

It seems like the upgraded packages don't depend directly on the new packages:

```
$ apt-cache depends kdeplasma-addons-data kwin-addons plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-runners-addons \ 
 | grep -E "libkf5purpose-bin|libkf5purpose5|libuv1|nodejs|qml-module-org-kde-purpose" \ 
&& echo dependencies found || echo dependencies not found
dependencies not found
```

How do I find out the nested dependency easily and is it possible to avoid installing the new packages?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to install new packages? As far as I can tell, running just `apt upgrade` will only update existing packages without touching any dependencies.

Comment: You can use `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade already existing packages. no new packages will be installed nor existing packages removed., in difference to `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`which will install new packages (if available) or remove obsolete packages (if necessary), see `man apt-get`.

Comment: `apt upgrade` wants to install the new packages as well. `apt-get upgrade` keeps back the addon updates I've tried to install with `dist-upgrade`. I think at least once the next kernel update is out, this is gonna be a problem.

Comment: Reason against new packages: I consider it a good practice to know your system and only install what is actually needed. Currently I can’t see what those new packages are needed for since none of the upgraded packages seem to depend on it.

Comment: Your *old* packages don't depend on those which `apt-get` wants to install. The *new* versions depend on them. `dist-upgrade` won't install new packages unless they are required by the new versions of already installed packages.  For example, [Ubuntu package search says](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/plasma-widgets-addons) that package `plasma-widgets-addons (4:5.10.5-0ubuntu2)` depends on `libkf5purpose5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `plasma-widgets-addons` in zesty doesn't depend on `libkf5purpose-bin` (and its dependencies), but the versions of this package in zesty-updates and artful do, thus upgrading this package cannot be achieved unless those extra dependencies are also installed.

`apt-get dist-upgrade` specifically allows for the installation of new packages.  If you only want to upgrade existing packages, without installing new ones, just use `apt-get upgrade` instead.  However, if there is a package that cannot be upgraded without installing a new dependency, it won't be upgraded.  It may still tell you it wants to upgrade that package, but it can't because it would require a new package.

Comment: Let’s assume I don’t need that version and a new kernel gets released. How do I install the kernel without installing this package?

Comment: You can use APT pinning to instruct APT never to upgrade to that version of  `plasma-widgets-addons`.  APT pinning is a general way to tell APT which packages not to upgrade, or which versions to avoid.